# Python kivy access between different blocks

Tags: python, properties, kivy

help me to understand the logic of kivy applications.
I'am doing a registration form. It has 2 screens: 1 - registration, application.
If the entered data is correct, then screen switches.

kv structure:

1) main.kv

```
    <Main>:
        WindowsScreen:
            win_screen: _win_screen
            id: _win_screen

    <WindowsScreen@ScreenManager>:
        RegistrationWindow
        ApplicationWindow  #name: 'application_window'
```

2) registration.kv

```
    <RegistrationWindow@Screen>:
        '''Here we describe appearance of the registration form
    and it also has 2 screens EnterScreen and RegistrationScreen, they are 
    described each in their file'''
        Registration:

    <Registration@ScreenManager>:
        EntryScreen
        RegistrationScreen
```

2) registration_screen.kv

```
    #: import registration_screen Registration.registration_screen
    <RegistrationScreen>:
        username: _username
        password: _password
        confirm_password: _confirm_password
        name: 'registration_screen' #between entry and registration
        AnchorLayout:
            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                size_hint: .8, .6
                row_force_default: True
                row_default_height: 30
                spacing: 5

                TextRegistration:
                    text: 'Username'
                TextInputRegistration:
                    text: 'Admin'
                    id: _username

                TextRegistration:
                    text: 'Password'
                TextInputRegistration:
                    text: 'Admin'
                    id: _password

                TextRegistration:
                    text: 'Confirm password'
                TextInputRegistration:
                    text: 'Admin'
                    id: _confirm_password
                Widget:
                ButtonRegistration:
                    text: 'Enter'
                    width: 250
                    on_press: root.access_is_allowed()
```

4) reistration_screen.py

```
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

    class RegistrationScreen(Screen):
        username = ObjectProperty(None)
        password = ObjectProperty(None)
        confirm_password = ObjectProperty(None)
        win_screen = ObjectProperty(None)

        def access_is_allowed(self):
            if self.username.text == 'Admin' and \
                  self.password.text == 'Admin' and \
                      self.confirm_password.text == 'Admin':

                self.parent.parent.parent.win_screen.current = 'application_window'
```

self is RegistrationScreen (Screen)
    from here we search win_screen

.parent is Registration (ScreenManager)

.parent is RegistrationWindow (Screen)

.parent is WindowScreen(ScreenManager)
    and it contain win_screen

How to do it correctly?
How can I access between different blocks

Comment: i made it this way

in main.py
        class Application(AnchorLayout):
        pass

    class main(App):

        root_screen_manager = ObjectProperty(None)


        def build(self):

            start_application = Application()
            self.root_screen_manager = start_application.root_manager
            return start_application

Comment: main.kv
<Application>:
    root_manager: root_manager

    ScreenManager:                      #application root screen manager
        id: root_manager
        transition: NoTransition()
        RW:                          #registration screen
        ApplicationWindow:

in registration_screen.kv 
win_screen: app.root_screen_manager
and in registration_screen.py
win_screen = ObjectProperty(None)

Now i can change screens in any file and place in program